# Getting MySQL code from an existing database

Tags: mysql

I have a database (mdb file) that I am currently busy with. I would like to know if it is possible to generate MySQL code that would be used to create this database?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you saying that you have a Microsoft Access database that you're "busy" with, and you'd like to create an identical schema in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of tools you can look at to try to do the conversion.

1. DataPump
2. Microsoft DTS (Nos Called SQL Server Integration Services)

Other option might be generate MySQL code from Access' DB MetaData you can access from JDBC, ODBC, ADO.NET or any other database access technology with metadata support. For this option you need to generate a piece of code (script). So it will only make sense if your access DataBase has a lot of table with a lot of columns or if you are planning to do this task several times.

Of course, using one of the mentioned tools will be faster if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly write DDL to create and populate a MySQL database from the work that you've already done on Microsoft Access.  Just put it in a text file that you execute using [MySQL batch](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html) and you're all set.

If you intend to keep going with developing both, you'll want to think about how you'll keep the two in synch.